# generic path for files

Tags: android, c++, aide-ide

Im not sure what it is called but ill do my best to explain it. I did search here on stack exchange and found this answer for an allias for path but i dont want to set a variable for it and i already know that. [create alias for path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890426/create-alias-for-path)

What I need is and its been along time since I seen it but its used with a % or $ or something that when the program runs from the directory it knows where the directory for the game files are. It didn't matter what the directory the program is in as long as the directory 'gameFiles' is in that directory it will work.

Here's my path:

```
"/storage/emulated/0/MyGame/MyHackGame/jni/gameFiles/oscom.txt"
```

I think its something like:

```
"%or$/gameFiles/oscom.txt"
```

The main problem is I have a project on source forge and don't want my developers to have to change these paths like 100 times to run the program and then I'll have to change them back.

Also iam using aide for android to make the program and using the standard c++ libaray do this might be difficult to do. I'm not even sure if I can add libarays with aide and native code or how to do it.

Comment: You can make a symbolic link

Comment: What exactly do you want to expand/match the wildcard expression `%or$` to? From you path format I suppose you're addressing unix like filesystem style only, or should that work for windows filesystem pathes as well?

Comment: What's a symbolic link it that the name of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Oh crap, I'd like it to work on both and be cross platform?

Comment: I'm working with aide on android but if its possible I'd like to code things to be cross platform?

Comment: @JasonLickliter Well, [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) provides some good cross platform approach to deal with file path expressions. Along with using `std::regex` or `boost::regex`, I could well imagine solutions to resolve to a final complete path.

Comment: Are you looking for environment variables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)? You can read them using the `getenv()` function from within a C program.

Comment: I got a project on source forge and I don't want other developers having to change say 100 paths to get the program to run and then I'll have to change them back to run it.

Comment: @JasonLickliter: Use some constant expression. In C this can easily be achived on code level by `#define MYPATH "/my/random/path/"`. and then code `... = fopen(MYPATH"gameFiles/oscom.txt", ...`

Comment: Ok I updated and edited the question to make it more clear. Sorry for that I don't want down votes this time.

Comment: Your edit seems to be worth another question.

Comment: Ok I'll try that alk

Comment: Oh great so I'm getting down votes again.

Comment: It's not you being downvoted, but question.

Comment: You know  πάντα ῥεῖ brings up a good point cause isn't windows paths back slashes and not forward slashes? C:\windows\directory? So that's a problem with this running on windows no matter what.

Comment: Are you doing C or C++, btw?

Comment: Well I'm not really asking how to add a libaray. I'd rather stick to standard c++

Comment: C++ (I have to add more characters)

Comment: @JasonLickliter `boost` libraries are designed to be used in cross platform environments (they're even considered as _pre-standard_ proposals sometimes). I don't have any specific experience with android and the aide-ide, but I think it should be possible to integrate it with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use symlinks as Eugene has suggested or modify build scripts to generate user specific paths into binaries or spearate files at build time. These are ignored by version tracking, so no more double mills. Another way might be checking env variables at runtime.

Comment: You could add some examples to make your answer more valuable.